# Is there a way to dynamically increase an array size in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, sizeof

I apologize if the title is misleading as I don't know how to refer to this, but I'll describe it and unlike my last post, ill be as descriptive as I can.

What I'm talking about is a program I made that asks for your grades in your classes, and turns them into an average, the problem is that this program heavily relies on preset values for things like the amount of subjects it takes into consideration when making an average

Below is what I have as of now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int grades[6];
 int sum,average;

 printf("Type in your grades for your main classes (SEPERATE WITH SPACES)\n");
 scanf("%i%i%i%i",&grades[0],&grades[1],&grades[2],&grades[3],&grades[4],&grades[5],&grades[6]);

 //determine average
 sum = grades[0] + grades[1] + grades[2] + grades[3];
 average = sum / 4;
 
 //print average
 printf("Your average is %i",average);
 return 0;
}
```

I feel like pointers could probably solve this with things like malloc() and sizeof() but I don't know how to use pointers that well. Something I might try is using a function to do it say, per scanf() call.

The output I want:

```
Type in your grades for your main classes (SEPERATE WITH SPACES)
95 95 95 95 92 93
Your average is 94 //I'm aware this is going to be a repeating decimal unless you use round()
```

Except I want it to properly determine the average regardless of how many numbers you put in.

TLDR; I want something like std::vector from c++ that I can dynamically increase while also being able to refer to it with ease and not have to type out a whole essay as you can see above.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Thanks to the people that commented, I know now that arrays are completely static, and the only way to efficiently expand them is to make one with malloc() and then add to it with realloc() as shown here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int *numbers = (int*)malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
 int *add_numbers = realloc(numbers,200 * sizeof(numbers)); //pointer that lets us add to the array with realloc()

 //print size in bytes to console
 printf("Size is %i",sizeof(numbers));
 free(add_numbers); //free memory
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you know about `malloc` and `realloc` yes that is the C way.

Comment: Thank you guys! Ill check these out as soon as possible!

Comment: @bolov I know about them but all of the tutorials I've seen on them just tell me "malloc() allocates memory in bytes" and that's it

Comment: @cs07: what else do you need to know?

Comment: @rici idk, i just thought it would be more useful though after looking at the question mine duplicated, i see why their useful now

Comment: honestly doing it with `malloc()` and `realloc()` is kind of annoying, I might just make a big array that is the max most logical number that i'll have, and then quit the program if the user puts in more elements then the max number

Comment: @cs07 yes, that can be a valid strategy depending on the requirements of your program, especially if it's a toy program or a program where you want to learn/practice other concepts. One thing to look our for that is a stack array cannot be very big.

Comment: @cs07: Personally, I find it more irritating to constantly have to check for overflow. If you're doing that anyway, you might as just expand the vector; it's no more work than issuing an error message and quitting. Just write some functions (or macros if you want to handle different element types), put them into a header, and you won't have to think about it again. This sort of thing is what C coding is about. Alternatively, these days, you can chose between tons of other programming languages with different annoyances :-)

Comment: array size is not the real issue here. You need no array at all. average is just a sum and a division. Since you do not know the number of elements the simple way is to use `fgets()` and read a single big line into memory. And then use `sscanf()` to parse the line 1 number at a time, sum them up and at the end divide the sum by the number of items.

Comment: @arfneto I know, I just wanted an excuse to use them since I pretty much never do, I know very well you can just write `int grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4;int sum = grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4;`, as for `sscanf()` and `fgets()` I've never thought of it that way, sounds a lot easier though

Comment: @bolov, its both a toy and learning program, that's why it doesn't really matter for me, though I can understand in a professional environment this would be a bad thing

Comment: @cs07 ok! Just use `sum += grade`, `total+=1` until `sscanf()` returns `0` on reading a new grade from the buffer read with `fgets()`.  Just 2 `int` for the sum and count. If you need post a new question on that and maybe I could add an example

Comment: oh ok thanks for the help, I'll try as soon as I can